# Retrieve relationship from a child instance on MongoDB

Tags: mongodb, mongoose

In **MongoDB**, I have a `One-To_many` reference relationship.
`A` has many `B`.
A has a property called `B_ids`, so I can retrieve all the `B` instances owned by a a particular `A` instance.

My question is: looking to an instance of `B`, how can I retrieve the `A` instance that owns it?

Thanks!

Comment: NB:  I would like to know what method could I use **on B** to retrieve its A instance!

Answer (score 1):

In order to do that you can try this:

```
var personSchema = Schema({
  _id: Schema.Types.ObjectId,
  name: String,
  age: Number,
  stories: [{ type: Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'Story' }]
});

var storySchema = Schema({
  author: { type: Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'Person' },
  title: String,
  fans: [{ type: Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'Person' }]
});
```

in this way you can retrieve A from B using populate.

```
Story.find().populate('author')
```

> Example borrowed from mongoose [populate](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/populate.html) website.

Comment: Thanks for your unswer! I would like to know what method could I use **on B** to retrieve its A instance!